# Bibliography does not appear at all while using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Having read the comments and following advise on how to use `biblatex` from [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management#Modern_style_.28biblatex.29) I have create the following structure (which still does not produce the bibliography correctly):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% everything that this documentclass requires
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
http://www.cs.put.poznan.pl/csobaniec/software/latex/files/dcsbook.cls
http://www.cs.put.poznan.pl/csobaniec/software/latex/files/dcslib.sty

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% thesis.tex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,thesis]{dcsbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references}

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\author{YYY}
\title{XXX}
\supervisor{ZZZ}
\date{Poznań, 2014}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents{}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

aa \cite{StoicaChord}  bbbb

\backmatter

\printbibliography

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% references.bib
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
@article{StoicaChord,
        Author = {Ion Stoica and Robert Morris and David Liben{-}Nowell and David R. Karger and M. Frans Kaashoek and Frank Dabek and Hari Balakrishnan},
        Bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, http://dblp.org},
        Biburl = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/journals/ton/StoicaMLKKDB03},
        Date-Modified = {2014-10-15 01:28:44 +0000},
        Doi = {10.1109/TNET.2002.808407},
        Journal = {{IEEE/ACM} Trans. Netw.},
        Number = {1},
        Pages = {17--32},
        Timestamp = {Wed, 15 Oct 2014 01:53:37 +0200},
        Title = {Chord: a scalable peer-to-peer lookup protocol for internet applications},
        Url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TNET.2002.808407},
        Volume = {11},
        Year = {2003},
        Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TNET.2002.808407}}
```

The `.tex` files complies itself to pdf, but the bibliography is not present in the output. The reference to the only one bibliography item, instead of being rendered as a number, this is [**1**], is rendered as follows: [**StoicaChord**].

Comment: Could you tell us which `TeX` distribution are you using? Are you compiling well your document? Is `biber` installed on your system? Is it well configured within your LaTeX Editor?

I had the same problem like you because I installed MikTeX of 64 bits that doesn't includes `biber` yet, and in another computers the path to biber was wrong.

Comment: After of download `logopp-sygnet-en.pdf`, put it in a directory `logopp`, add `.bib` to `references` (`\addbibresource{references.bib}`), and run `pdflatex`->`bibtex`->`pdflatex` it shows perfectly!!

Comment: @skpblack - thanks!! It worked. I just wonder how the hell did you know to include logopp-sygnet-en.pdf ? I didn't get any error stating that this file was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to traditional BibTeX style files, with `biblatex` the correct syntax is

```
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

i.e., including the `.bib` filename extension.